# #springFormInput Sytex problem

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

`#springFormInput("userForm.password" 'type="password"')` is not working;

is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#springFormPasswordInput("userForm.password" "")`

([list of all macros](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/view.html#views-form-macros))

Comment: Thanks it's now working. Can you please provide any reference links for velocity spring form macros